# CORS causing error for sending GCM

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, google-cloud-messaging, cors

I am trying to send GCM through an AJAX request but it is failing. I am getting Preflight and Access-Origin errors. I have searched web a lot but couldn't find a resolution that will help me fix my problem. I am using Google Documentation to send message, but it is failing when I am using JQuery/Angular $ajax/$http method. Please see my code below and let me know what can be done to make it work. Your help is appreciated.

```
var gcmRequest = {
     method: 'POST', url: GCM_URL,
     data: {
        registration_ids: registrantsArray, collapse_key: collapseKey, delay_while_idle: delayWhileIdle,
        time_to_live: timeToLive, data: dataToSent, dry_run: dryRun
     },
     headers: { Authorization: "key=" + ApiKey, 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
                }// End of request config


$http(gcmRequest).then(
     function (response) {
        strMessageToReturn += "\nResponse\n\n" + JSON.stringify(response);
        processResponse(response, tempRegistrants).then(
            function (response) {
                strMessageToReturn += "\n\n" + response;
                if (counter == totalSets) { deferred.resolve(strMessageToReturn); }
        }, function (error) { }, function (updates) { /*strMessageToReturn += updates;*/ });
 },
                function (error) {
                    strErrorToReturn += "\nError\n\n" + JSON.stringify(error);
                    deferred.reject(strErrorToReturn);
```

});